# Call Vuex Getters from another javascript file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

In /store/user/getters.js:

```
function getLoggedIn (state) {
  return state.loggedIn
}
```

In another file: router-auth.js, I try to get the getters.getLoggedIn's value (true or false) like this:

```
import user from '../store/user'
const loggedIn = user.getters.getLoggedIn
console.log(user.getters.getLoggedIn)
```

Oddly, it returns the source code of the function instead of the state's value! When I print the log of `user.getters`, it does list the functions.

Comment: You need to import the store instance and access the getter through it.  Doing it the way you are now is just assigning a function to a variable

Comment: @Steven, can you elaborate on "import the store instance"? I have imported the store 'user' module  `import user from '../store/user'`. The vuex action works well inside the Vue components. The trouble is inside another JS file (router-auth.js). Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you call the getter as a function? eg. `console.log(user.getters.getLoggedIn())`?

Comment: does `/store/user` create a store (call `new Vuex.store()`) or is a module?

Comment: @Steven. User is a module inside the store. ```export default function () {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      user
    },

    // enable strict mode (adds overhead!)
    // for dev mode only
    strict: process.env.DEV
  })

  return Store
}```

Comment: @zcoop98 No. I tried that too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the instance of the store.

```
const myStore = new Vuex.store({...});
```

Here `myStore` is the instance.

Assuming your store looks something like

**store.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import user from "./user";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    user
  }
});

export default store;
```

You can access the instance by importing `store` from `store.js`.

**router-auth.js**

```
import store from './store.js';

function someAuthFunction() {
    console.log(store.getters.getLoggedIn);
}
```

A simple [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-haibt-t5d86?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) on CodeSandbox

Comment: Thanks, Steven. Your code works well. Mine still doesn't. I console.log the 'user', which is an object. However, `user.getters.getLoggedIn` is still a literal. Pulling hair ...  (I am working inside the Quasar Framework which handles the Vuex boot. There must be one step that I have missed.)

Comment: @XPLi is your store creation wrapped inside of a function?  if so everytime you import from store it would create a new store causing it to not work.

Comment: Indeed, it is!  I changed the index.js of the store like below and it works: ```let store = null

export default function () {
  store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      user
    },
    plugins: [createPersistedState()], // to persist

    // enable strict mode (adds overhead!)
    // for dev mode only
    strict: process.env.DEV
  })

  return store
}

export { store }``` Finally! Good to have it fixed before the weekend.